# How to use the next index of an array in a for..of + if condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm creating a word filter that if index 1 = dog and index 2 = cat, it will return true. What should I put in next index for word?

```js
let textContainer = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

for (let word of textContainer) {
  if (word === 'dog' && (next index for word) === 'cat') {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: use a normal `for(let i; i < ...)` so you can do `i + 1`

Comment: ... or use `.forEach()`, which passes the index to the callback.

Comment: @Pointy that can't work, note that the code tries to `return`.

Comment: @CherryDT oh right, well maybe `.find()` or `.findIndex()` then.

Comment: You want array `some()`

Comment: See [Javascript: Generic get next item in array](/q/16294835/4642212) and [How to find previous and next object of an Array for a active object?](/q/70563387/4642212).

Comment: or `for (let [i, word] of textContainer.entries()) {` to access the `[index, value]` entry tuples of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal `for (let i = 0; i < textContainer.length; i++)` so you can check `i + 1`

```js
let textContainer = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

function checkTextArray() {
  for (let i = 0; i < textContainer.length; i++) {
    if (textContainer[i] === 'dog' && textContainer[i + i] === 'cat') {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const res = checkTextArray()
console.log(res);
```

Comment: this is what I should have done on the first try. thank you!

Comment: or `for (let [i, word] of textContainer.entries()) {`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

`find` returns "dog" which is not undefined (so truthy) if dog is next to cat.

`some` will return true if dog, cat are found and false if not

Since your comments show you wanted a true/false function, I made you one.

```js
const textArray = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

const areAdjacent = (word1, word2, arr) => arr
  .some((word, i, arr) => word===word1 && arr[i+1] === word2);

console.log(areAdjacent("dog","cat",textArray))
console.log(areAdjacent("tiger","bird",textArray))
```

Using Pilchard's example

```js
const textArray = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

const areAdjacent = (word1, word2, arr) => arr
  .some((word, i, {[i+1]: nextWord}) => word === word1 && nextWord === word2);

console.log(areAdjacent("dog", "cat", textArray))
console.log(areAdjacent("tiger", "bird", textArray))
```

Comment: this definitely looks more reading friendly. Although I'll have to study this first to better understand it. Thank you!

Comment: I did not know what you wanted with the return statement, I thought you had a function. I rewrote it as a function, I am using `some` because it returns true when found and false when not.

Comment: also somewhat opaque shorthand `.some((word, i, {[i+1]: nextWord}) =>`

Answer (score 1):

a `for of` loop is not going to let you do that. You could do it with a normal for or while loop, but arrays have built in methods that can make it easy to do.

You want to use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will allow you to get the index and reference the array you are looping over to get the next index.

```js
let textContainer = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

const result = textContainer.some((text, index, array) => text === 'dog' && array[index+1] === 'cat'); 

console.log(result);
```

If you want to know where in the array it is, that would be [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findindex)

```js
let textContainer = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger'];

const result = textContainer.findIndex((text, index, array) => text === 'dog' && array[index+1] === 'cat'); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need explicit iteration at all. You can simply get the `indexOf()` the first word and then just access the next element.

```js
let textArray = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger',];

const areAdjacent = (word1, word2, arr) => {
  const i = arr.indexOf(word1);

  return i !== -1 && arr[i + 1] === word2;
};

console.log(areAdjacent('dog', 'cat', textArray));
console.log(areAdjacent('tiger', 'bird', textArray));
```

Or if you're wedded to a single line functional solution wrap it in an IIFE

```js
let textArray = ['bird', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'rabbit', 'ox', 'sheep', 'tiger',];

const areAdjacent = (word1, word2, arr) =>
  ((i) => i !== -1 && arr[i + 1] === word2)(arr.indexOf(word1));

console.log(areAdjacent('dog', 'cat', textArray));
console.log(areAdjacent('tiger', 'bird', textArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the indexOf method to return the **index** of a specific element,
then use the **index**+1 to find the next element for the given one in the array.

The code could be like this:

```js
let textContainer = 
[  "bird",
  "dog",
  "cat",
  "snake",
  "rabbit",
  "ox",
  "sheep",
  "tiger",];

for (let word of textContainer) {
  var index = textContainer.indexOf(word);
  if (word === "dog" && textContainer[index + 1] === "cat") {
    console.log("Cat is next of Dog!");
    // return true;
    //if you're inside a function.
  }
}
```

Good luck!